# jest --coverage not generating report

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I want to put some functions (sum, mul, sub, div) in the test file just like below,

```
import {describe, expect} from "@jest/globals";

function sum(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}

const div = (a,b) => {
    return a/b;
}

const mul = (a,b) => {
    return a*b;
}

const sub = (a,b) => {
    return a-b;
}

describe('testing', ()=> {
    
    it('test', ()=> {
        expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
    });

    it('test2', ()=> {
        expect(mul(2,2)).toBe(4);
    });
});
```

When I hit the command `npm test -- --coverage`, it will generate report just like below,
[image]

If you see in report in above image, both test cases are passing but table shows 0 in every column, that means it is not detecting those functions.

**What to do here?**

**Note: I don't want to shift those functions (sum, mul, sub, div) outside the file. I want to keep those functions in that test file only.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after **forceCoverageMatch** jest config option

From jest docs:
*"Test files are normally ignored from collecting code coverage. With this option, you can overwrite this behavior and include otherwise ignored files in code coverage."*

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  forceCoverageMatch: ['**/*.t.js'],
};

export default config;
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Comment: Hey do you also know, how to run test cases in custom sequence ?

Comment: May that will help you https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testsequencer-string

Comment: I checked this earlier, but i did not understand anything from there, that's why I asked you. If you have implmented this, then share with me, thanks